# Android Share functionality with one active app

Tags: java, android, android-activity, authentication, share

I am writing an application which lets the user login to a **webservice** which is displayed inside a webview.
The user should be able to upload pictures to the **webservice** through the share functionality from the camera app for example.
My problem is: I don't want to force the user to put the user name every time he makes an upload. But every time I use the share functionality a new instance of my app gets open inside a seperate "Gallery" card, which does not have the login data when I logged in the last time.
I don't want to persist the login data for safety reasons.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Activities can be swapped out any moment (that is the whole idea of android) so if you do not persist the login info, it is just not possible using only an activity.

You could use a service or extend the Application, which can stay in memory in the background and let that one hold the login info in the background. (when using an application you still need a dummy service to keep it in memory). But when ever the phone restarts, the user has to logon again.

Comment: I have no issue with the user to login again once he restarted his phone. But if I started the app once and logged in, I dont want to login if I suddenly wanted to share a picture. The app has already the user data temporarly.

Comment: I want the share functionalty to call the already opened app and not open a new instance with the name of the sharing app e.g. "gallery"

Comment: then also add "singleinstance" to your activity in the manifest

Comment: this helps but I cant get the imageURI through getParcelbleExtra.

Comment: That is a whole other discussion, look for solutions on stackoverflow